# Sending SMTP email from PHP Script hosted on Hostgator Servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I have created a web application as such in the application I require to send to send users their passwords if they have forgotten them. Now I use a gmail account to send the email. When I send the email locally from my machine using XAMPP everything works fine and it delivers as expected. When I look to put the php script onto a Hostgator server and try send the user their password I can't. But the reason I think this is happening is because Gmail immediately send me the following:

```
Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account myemail@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as an email client or mobile device. 

We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt: 

Tuesday, January 21, 2014 1:42:56 PM UTC 
IP Address: 198.57.247.245 (gator3281.hostgator.com.) 
Location: Los Angeles, CA, USA


If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and reset your password immediately
```

Based on this email I would assume that Gmail is touchy that hostgator is trying to send an email via them. My problem is I don't know how to fix this problem (This is my first time doing something like this) As such I was using a PHP framework called codeigniter and here is the code used to send the email (Note this code works more than fine locally i.e. I dont think there is anything wrong with the code):

```
public function SendEmailValidate($email,$subject,$message,$type)
    {
        $config = array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                        'smtp_port' => 465,
                        'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                        'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
                        'smtp_timeout' => 30,
                        'mailtype' => $type
                        );
        $CI = &get_instance();

        $CI->load->library('email',$config);
        $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $CI->email->from('myemail@gmail.com','Book Bay');
        $CI->email->to($email);
        $CI->email->subject($subject);
        $CI->email->message($message);

        if($CI->email->send())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any help on this matter would really help, thanks

Comment: Why not try other services like Mailchimp or Sendgrid for sending transactional emails ? They are very easy to integrate too

Comment: you can use php mail function to send email from your hostgator server and set reply-path-to : myemail@gmail.com...so the one who recives your email will see the from and reply to address as myemail@gmail.com..if you need i can post one answer with the php mail function code..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its in your gmail settings; you need to allow your website to send emails;

to do so go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue; then useyour website to send email an email; and google will detect your login attempt and allow you.

Comment: In my case I had to use the following link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and enable less secure apps

Comment: This works for me, but why is this only required on some hostings?

Comment: First of all you are a champion. Second, this for me was required on top of 'Less secure apps' being enabled for my automated web system to be able to send messages, as it was getting the 'sign in attempt blocked' issue. Cannot understand why this is so poorly documented to this day in the Google support forums.